# Jackson custom serializer ignore @JsonIdentityInfo

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson, jsonserializer

I created a JacksonList class and JacksonListSerializer (extending JSonSerializer) for resolve a issue with collections and inheritance classes. Works fine.

The problem is that serializer ignore JsonIdentityInfo "rules". I have mapping exceptions like "Already had POJO for id (java.lang.Integer) .."

I put example below:

JacksonList.java

```
@JsonSerialize(using = JacksonListSerializer.class)
class JacksonList<E> extends ArrayList<E> {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
}
```

JacksonListSerializer.java

```
public class JacksonListSerializer extends JsonSerializer<JacksonList<?>> {

    @Override
    public void serialize(JacksonList<?> list, JsonGenerator generator, SerializerProvider provider)
            throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        generator.writeStartArray();
        if (list != null) {
            for (Object item : list) {

                generator.writeObject(item);
            }
        }
        generator.writeEndArray();
    }
}
```

FirstItem.java

```
public class FirstItem {

    private Son son;

    public Son getSon() {
        return son;
    }

    public void setSon(Son son) {
        this.son = son;
    }
}
```

Son.java

```
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator=ObjectIdGenerators.IntSequenceGenerator.class, property="@id", scope=Son.class)
public class Son {


    public Son(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    private String text;

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }


}
```

Main.java
            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

```
        FirstItem f1 = new FirstItem();
        FirstItem f2 = new FirstItem();

        JacksonList<FirstItem> jacksonList = new JacksonList<FirstItem>();
        List<FirstItem> list = new ArrayList<FirstItem>();

        Son son = new Son();

        f1.setSon(son);
        f2.setSon(son);

        list.add(f1);
        list.add(f2);

        jacksonList.add(f1);
        jacksonList.add(f2);



        System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(jacksonList));
        System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(list));
```

Output:

```
{"JacksonList":[{"FirstItem":{"id":1,"son":{"type":"com.Son","@id":1}}},{"FirstItem":{"id":2,"son":{"type":"com.Son","@id":1}}}]}

{"ArrayList":[{"id":1,"son":{"type":"com.Son","@id":1}},{"id":2,"son":1}]}
```

As you can see in the second case (print of ArrayList) the information of the Son class are not duplicated. But in the first case the object son is put two times.